# Deadbeef doesn't show up in sound applet of Cinnamon

Tags: arch-linux, audio, cinnamon, deadbeef

I have installed Cinnamon desktop, VLC and Deadbeef. When I play an audio file or a video with VLC, I can control it via the sound applet, but when I play music from Deadbeef, there is no signal from the sound applet.

I found that Deadbeef is supported with the sound applet, here is a quote from sound applet.js:

> /* global values */
>
> let players_without_seek_support = ['spotify', 'totem', 'gnome-mplayer', 'pithos'];
>
> let players_with_seek_support = [
>      'clementine', 'banshee', 'rhythmbox', 'rhythmbox3', 'pragha', 'quodlibet',
>       'amarok', 'xnoise', 'gmusicbrowser', 'vlc', 'qmmp', 'deadbeef', 'audacious'];

So, how can I configure my system to make the sound applet controls deadbeef?

Please help me!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet that sound applet is using MPRIS protocol to discover and communicate with players. Try to install mpris-plugin for Deadbeef: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/deadbeef-mpris2-plugin/